# jQuery ganttView multiple segments per line

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

A few days ago i discovered the ganttView plugin for jquery.
Lightweight and brilliant.

My question is the following.
IsS there a way to have multiple segments per line?
Say, for Project 1 i have Phase 1 going from the 10 of march until the 13 of march. then that process is picked up again on the 16th of march until the 20th of march.
How could i go about representing that?

Still related to this plugin.
Is there a way to have a segment extend on multiple lines? say 2, 3 lines thick?
That is if i have this to go hand in hand in parallel?

Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

From the project page:

> Many people have been asking for more advanced features such
>   as...multiple items per line. While I would love to be able to add all
>   of these features I just don't have the time and it's often not within
>   the scope of why I created the plugin. However, I would be extremely
>   happy to accept any pull requests from anyone interested in adding
>   these features. If you like the plugin, feel free to fork it and
>   submit your patches back.

Comment: Thank you for the reply man.
I saw that too on the git page. I was just wondering if anyone had gotten their hands into it.
Took a look at the source and i think i could manage something. But the fact is that i'm a lot more prolific on server side languages and though i can manage enough js, the code has no comments whatsoever.
So i'm gonna hava to benchmark everything and see if i can swing it.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is included in the fork https://github.com/mivano/jquery.ganttView